# Javascript - Submission form Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have encountered an error when trying to submit this second form (latlngform) that dynamically appears according to the response provided in the first form. I have not tested whether the script in the `submit()` function works as the error does not allow my program to continue.

```
Error:
jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/.../index.html.
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource
```

Below is the erroneous part of my code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="pagefive">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Location of Meeting</h1>
    <a href="#pageone" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Go back</a>
    <a href="#mypanel" class="hamburger">&#9776;</a>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <div data-role="content" id="content">
      <form id="inputpax" action='#pagefive'>
        <select name="pax" id="pax" data-inline="true">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitpax" />
      </form>

      <div data-role="content" id="latlngform"></div>

      <div id="map" style="height: 400px;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel">
    <ul>
      <a href="#pagetwo">Create Meetings</a><br/>
      <a href="#pagethree">Display meetings</a><br/>
      <a href="#pageseven">Past Meetings</a><br/>
      <a href="#pagefive">Find Midpoint</a><br/>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $("#inputpax").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var selectList = document.getElementById("pax");
    var pax = selectList.options[selectList.selectedIndex].value;
    var form = "<form id='inputLatLng' action='#pagefive' >";
    for (count = 0; count < pax; count++) {
      form += "<div class='ui-field-contain'> <label for='location'>Latitude " + (count + 1) + " :</label><input type='text' id='lat" + count + "' data-clear-btn='true'></div><div class='ui-field-contain'><label for='location'>Longitude " + (count + 1) + " :</label><input type='text' id='long" + count + "' data-clear-btn='true'></div>";
    }
    form += "<input type='hidden' value='" + pax + "' id='noOfPax' />";
    form += "<input type='submit' value='Submit' id='submit'></form>";
    document.getElementById("latlngform").innerHTML = form;
  });

  $("#inputLatLng").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var noPax = document.getElementById("noOfPax");
    console.log(noPax);
    var locations = [];
    for (count = 0; count < noPax; count++) {
      var latStr = lat + count;
      var longStr = long + count;
      console.log("hi2");
      var latitude = document.getElementById(latStr);
      var longitude = document.getElementById(longStr);
      console.log("hi3");
      locations.push([latitude, longitude]);
    }

    var bound = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      bound.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]));

              // OTHER CODE
            }

    var centreLatLng = bound.getCenter();

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 18,
      center: centreLatLng,
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });

    var markercenter = new google.maps.Marker({

      position: centreLatLng,
      title: "test Centre",
      animation: google.maps.Animation.Drop

    });
    markercenter.setMap(map);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: "This is the centre location. <br/> You can find a desired meetup point within 100m radius of this marker."
    });

    markercenter.addListener('click', function() {
      markercenter.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
      infowindow.open(map, markercenter);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Note: For example, if `3` was chosen in the form `inputpax`, 3 latitude and longitude fields will be shown in the form `latlngform`. The error message appears in the console log after clicking on the `Submit` button in `latlngform`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP." error when loading a local file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local). You need to run is from a Webserver locally.

Comment: Is this a single page application? Do you use a framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I solved my problem..
Instead of declaring the `<form>` and `form id` in the innerHTML tag, declaring it as a HTML tag worked.

My code is as follows:

```
<form id="inputLatLng" action='#pagefive'>
    <div data-role="content" id="latlngform"></div>
</form>

<script>
    $("#inputpax").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var selectList = document.getElementById("pax");
        var pax = selectList.options[selectList.selectedIndex].value;
        var form = "";
        for (count = 0; count < pax; count++) {
            form += "<div class='ui-field-contain'> <label for='location'>Latitude " + (count + 1) + " :</label><input type='text' id='lat" + count + "' data-clear-btn='true'></div><div class='ui-field-contain'><label for='location'>Longitude " + (count + 1) + " :</label><input type='text' id='long" + count + "' data-clear-btn='true'></div>";
        }
        form += "<input type='hidden' value='" + pax + "' id='noOfPax' />";
        form += "<input type='submit' value='Generate' id='submitlatlng' />";
        document.getElementById("latlngform").innerHTML = form;
      });
</script>
```

Hope it helps anyone who stumbles across this problem as well. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

> submit is not a function

means that you named your submit button or some other element `submit`. Rename the button to `btnSubmit` and your call will magically work.

When you name the button submit, you override the `submit()` function on the form.